# Hyperledger Fabric Rest API multiple user authentication

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I deployed a Hyperledger Fabric API with command:

```
-> composer-rest-server -c admin@mynetwork -a true -m true
```

i have my local environment variable like this:

```
export COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
  "github": {
    "provider": "github",
    "module": "passport-github",
    "clientID": "e3e9af5103fde6d4cc54",
    "clientSecret": "45ce6aaa9ff142cafd73c0b35509713ab24c627b",
    "authPath": "/auth/github",
    "callbackURL": "/auth/github/callback",
    "successRedirect": "/",
    "failureRedirect": "/"
  }
}'
```

I have authentication in github like this:
Homepage URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

Authorization Callback URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback
```

I also have one client web app, that is doing authentication in Github.

PROBLEM:
my web client completes authentication in github and i save the access_token in a cookie. then i execute the post to upload my id card like this with a file:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/wallet/import?name=myName&access_token="+$scope.access_token;
```

the problem is that after executing the post, i have this error:

```
statusCode":401,"name":"Error","message":"Authorization Required","code":"AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED"
```

What am i doing wrong? is this the environment variable? I can clearly see that the API is running, otherwise i wouldn't get this error message, but something is clearly wrong with the API authentication...

Answer (score 0):

to import a business network card as a file from disk it needs:

1) to be the right format - how did you build the business network card that you're trying to import via REST APIs? See https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/id-cards-playground.html . At a guess, it would appear that you are not actually importing a Composer business network card (with valid metadata, a connection.json file plus either enrolment id/secret or certificate/key to create a valid .card file ) using the REST APIs using the POST /wallet/import operation under /Wallets

2) The card file must be a valid .card (suffix) file to be able to import

Which version of Composer are you using?

Can you indicate which tutorial or document you followed to do so?

These details would help.

Comment: 1) the card i'm using is the admin card. It was created when i deployed the network...so it should be ok. Can you check the link you sent because it's not working.

Comment: 2) it is a .card file
Composer version is 0.16.3
I'm not following any tutorial....fully discovering this by myself, but if you have a good tutorial on how could i create a web client to interact with fabric and log in different users please let me know, i would be thankful to you for ever!
Thanks for the help!